# How do I add a click event to an inserted element

Tags: jquery, dom, element

Ok so I use this button once and then remove it. I then insert a new one. The problem is that the click event stops working. Not sure what is causing this and how I can fix it?

```
    $("#load_more_button").click(function () {
        //Do things
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Actaully you could have got this answer from some other post..there are about 100s of posts with the same issue... `click not working for dynamically added element`...

Anyways by using `.on` delegated event you can get it..

```
$(document).on("click","#load_more_button",function () {
    //Do things
});
```

If you search again you will get all the reasons saying why we need to delegate the events.. so I consider you doing that...

**As a note: delegating it to the closest static parent container rather than the document is better performance wise..**

Comment: That's fantastic guys thanks - would have taken me ages to find that out. I'll accept when it lets me :))

Comment: welcome... please go thorugh other post to get some idea of `on` delegated event... anyways glad it helped.. happy coding. :)